# LetsEncrypt on Domains

Tags: ssl, dns, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, domain-name

I've a domain name, `basecompany.com`. My application is deployed on the server and the IP has been mapped with the domain name in GoDaddy domain registrar DNS settings. Also, it is `https` enabled using Letsencrypt which automatically refreshes my certificate after every 3 months.

Now, I purchase 5 more domains and just want to reroute those 5 domains to `basecompany.com`. Nothing else. These are just URLs with no application server. So, I used domain-forwarding service.

However these 5 domains are not `https` secured. How do I apply letsencrypt certificated within my DNS settings itself, or do I have to separately purchase a SSL certificate from them?

```
PS: I'm skipping my option to add the domain name in my webserver (nginx) 
config file and then map the IP to my DNS of new domain names. I dont want this. 

I just want to install the certificate and it should start working.
```

Comment: If you are using a domain forwarding service and pointing to their IP, then only they can handle the SSL certificate.

Comment: `their` IP? Who's their?

Comment: The domain forwarding service, someone has to do the redirect on a server, that is where the SSL certificate will be installed, DNS nameservers do not handle SSL, only webservers do.

Comment: So, there's no away except to map my sub-domains IP to my base domain IP, and then reroute to the same destination?

Comment: At this point, I think you should spend some time learning more about the DNS system and the kinds of redirecting you can do there, if that doesn't work for you, then you do the redirect at the webserver level, which gives you full control over how it works. Once you dive in, you should have no problem getting the effect you want.